# Spring with Hibernate - SQL - return list of obejcts with nested list by condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I use Spring with Hibernate, MySQL, JPQL. I have such a method in my repository:

```
@Query("""
  SELECT w FROM Window w
  LEFT JOIN w.ramps r
  WHERE r.isDeleted = false
  AND w.id = :id
""")

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"warehouse", ...})
Optional<Window> findByIdWithNotDeletedRamps(long id);
```

My goal: I want to fetch all windows with dependent `ramps` but ONLY with not deleted `ramps` (`ramp.isDeleted = false`). If window has only deleted `ramps` then I should receive such a window with empty list of `ramps`

So far I fetched all windows and then in code filtered `window.ramps` with `Mapstruct` to receive `windows` with ONLY not deleted (`isDeleted` flag `= false`) ramps. I wonder HOW to write sql to receive `windows` with list of only not deleted `ramps`? Is it possible?

I've tried with the code above but it's a bad approach because when windows doesn't have any ramps then this particular `window` is not received.

Comment: *r.isDeleted = false* as part of the join not as part of where. This makes your left join to inner join `SELECT w FROM Window w
            LEFT JOIN w.ramps r on r.isDeleted = false
            WHERE w.id = :id`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DTO for this and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Window.class)
public interface WindowDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("ramps[isDeleted = false]")
    Set<RampDto> getRamps();

    @EntityView(Ramp.class)
    interface RampDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`WindowDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, WindowDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<WindowDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!